# 80s young adult book involving mind control aliens, a male teen protagonist whose mom is controlled and a teacher; there's also a drug

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, young-adult, drug

I'm looking for an 80s young adult book involving mind control aliens, a male teen protagonist whose mom is controlled and a teacher; there's also a drug. The mom takes her class out to get zapped away by the aliens and the protagonist doesn't go with them.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to recall the cover art or any of the character names?  Does it take place in a city or a small town?  Do you remember the country?  Also the question is a bit confusing - do you mean that the protagonist's mom is also his teacher?

Comment: Sorry - the protagonist's mom is a teacher, but not his, she teaches younger kids. The cover art is vague (it's been a looong time). but I think it was a school playground. I think the country was US, maybe CA and the story was set in a city, not sure if it was one I knew or recognized. Thanks!